# SQL:number of supplied values does not match table definition. From what I can see it does though?

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have created the table Orders then inserted the values but I keep getting this error.

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
    (
    orderNo             CHAR(8) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    orderDate           DATE NOT NULL,
    customerID          CHAR(8) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(customerID),
    employeeNumber      CHAR(8) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Staff(employeeNumber) NOT NULL, --Could possibly be many to many but I just interperated it as the staff member who takes the order. So not including staff who make or deliver.
    transactionID       CHAR(8) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES OrderPayments(transactionID) NOT NULL,
    orderstatus         BIT 
    )


    INSERT INTO Orders VALUES ('ORDER001','2017-04-20','PAT00001','ROBBIE11','TRANS001',1)
```

Anyone have any idea whats going on? Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that date is converted into a date value automatically?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: I am guessing this is SQL Server.  If so, it works fine:  http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler.  Perhaps you have a trigger on the table that is breaking things.

Comment: Yeah its SQL server. Its a pretty basic 1st year computer science assignment so no triggers are needed.

And thanks Bob but the date is correct and it works in other areas of the code fine.

Comment: I ran the same and there is no error. My `SQL` version is `2008 R2`. What is yours?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MEQB3.png

Comment: I used 2014 maybe it has something do do with the way the foreign keys are added.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved, It was due to the order I was inserting values into my tables. Order had data inserted before Staff which caused a Key conflict. Cheers for help

Comment: That's a good example on why listing the columns in the `INSERT` clause is good coding style: `insert into #orders (orderno, orderdate, ...) values (...)`